# Celery define workflows on the fly

Tags: python-3.x, celery, workflow

I am using **python 3.6.6** and **Celery 4.2.0.**

I am trying to manage **dynamic task workflows** which could change on the fly. Workflows may contain long and short duration steps.

For example:
Initially  I have the following task workflow:

[Initial workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idxsp.png)

But, at some point **I have to add another task which depends on A**. So task may wait until A finish:

[Desired workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiAsM.png)

```
   from __future__ import absolute_import
   from celery import subtask, signals
   from pymemcache.client import base
   from test_celery.celery import app
   import time

   def get_task_uuid(task):
      return str(hash(frozenset(task[0], task[1]))))

   @app.task
   def add(x, y):
       print('add({},{}) = {} | {}'.format(x, y, x+y, time.time()))

       return x+y

    @app.task
    def sub(x, y):
       print('sub({},{}) = {} | {}'.format(x, y, x-y, time.time()))
       return x-y

    @app.task
    def mul(x, y):
       time.sleep(10)
       print('mul({},{}) = {} | {}'.format(x,y,x*y, time.time()))
       return x*y

     @signals.before_task_publish.connect
     def before_task_publish(body, exchange, routing_key, headers, properties,  retry_policy, **kw):
         task = (body, headers['task'])
         uuid = get_task_uuid(task)
```

I've been looking for any possible approach, trying to listen task signals to make D run as soon as task A succeeds (signals.task_success). Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you could use [chains](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains)
and [link](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#callbacks) the result of the 1st task to call whatever task you want according to the result